# MvvMCross Binding with format string

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios, format, mvvmcross

How can i add a format for a binding, that formats the bound value with string.Format or something similar? I saw in other threads, that you can pass a converterName.

- Does a converter for this issue exists?
- Where can i see a list of the standard converters of MvvMCross v3?

I browsed the code shortly, but couldn't find something. I know that there could happen information lost which destroys two way binding, but i only want this for displaying values. 
My concrete case is Binding of a DateTime.

```
bindings.Bind(purchaseDate).To(vm => vm.RegisteredDevice.PurchaseDate);
```

my wish e.g.:

```
bindings.Bind(purchaseDate).To(vm => vm.RegisteredDevice.PurchaseDate).WithFormat("hh:mm");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To do this, you can just create a StringFormatValueConverter and you can use it's parameter as the format string to use.

Should take about 2 minutes to write... here, I'll prove it:

```
public class StringFormatValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        var format = "{0:" + parameter.ToString()  + "}";

        return string.Format(format, value);
    }
}
```

then

```
set.Bind(myLabel).To(vm => vm.TheDate).WithConversion("StringFormat", "HH:MM:ss");
```

1 minute 53 seconds ;)

Comment: thanks. I just want to get sure, that there isn't a converter implemented. Writing my own converter would have been my next step :) Now i can beat your time ^^ But one question is still open: Where can i see a list of the standard converters of MvvMCross v3?

Comment: easy answer - currently, in a standard 'HotTuna' app there are **none** (some can be added using plugins and one is currently requested for multi-language binding)

Comment: For those who want to write binding in xml and just need a float to string converter, `local:MvxBind="Text Format('{0:F2}', someFloat)"` works great here.

Comment: Felix's comment is about the Literal Binding feature which I'm assuming wasn't available back in 2013. It would be helpful if it was incorporated into the answer or at least posted as a new answer for more visibility