# MVVM Cross binding with complex format string

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios, format, mvvmcross

I have a requirement for an extension to [Stuart's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373321/stuart) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398341/mvvmcross-binding-with-format-string) relating to formatting a string in MVVM cross for iOS at runtime. I want to pass in a complex object at run time and evaluate it in the value convertor, to basically achieve the same thing I can on android with the Tibet binding like so:

```
 local:MvxBind="Text 'Awaiting ' + Name + ' For 10 Minutes' " />
```

**Tried so far**

```
set.Bind(txtTitle).To(vm => vm.Name).WithConversion("StringFormatPlus", new { before = "Awaiting", after = " For 10 minutes" });
```

I have tried casting the object parameter to dynamic but it requires a reference to Microsoft c sharp dll so I'm not sure that's the way to go.

```
public class StringFormatPlusValueConverter : MvxValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        var dynamicParameter = parameter as dynamic;
        var before = dynamicParameter.before;
        var after = dynamicParameter.after;

        var format = "{0} {1} {2}";

        return string.Format(format, before, value, after);
    }
}
```

The workaround I have been using is to create an additional getter property on the view model that I format how I like, and binding to that in the iOS view controller. It works but it's not ideal and clutters my view model with strongly coupled view logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want via Fluent Binding using the `SourceDescribed` method. Found in `MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext` namespace.

```
public MvxFluentBindingDescription<TTarget, TSource> SourceDescribed(MvxBindingDescription description);
public MvxFluentBindingDescription<TTarget, TSource> SourceDescribed(string bindingDescription);
```

**Implementation Example:**

```
set.Bind(txtTitle).SourceDescribed("'Awaiting ' + Name + ' For 10 Minutes'");
```